# How can i add an image field in focus point wizard of bw_focuspoint_images typo extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I want to add an image field in focus point wizard of bw_focuspoint_images typo extension. Please help. I have added an Image text field by using following code PageTS. But I want that field type to a file upload not a text type. when I give type=file its not working.

```
mod.tx_bwfocuspointimages.settings.fields {

name {
    title = LLL:EXT:bw_focuspoint_images/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:wizard.fields.name
    type = text
}

description {
    title = LLL:EXT:bw_focuspoint_images/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:wizard.fields.description
    type = textarea
}

image {
    title = LLL:EXT:bw_focuspoint_images/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:wizard.fields.image
    type = text
}

color {
    title = LLL:EXT:bw_focuspoint_images/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:wizard.fields.color
    type = select
    options {
        red = LLL:EXT:bw_focuspoint_images/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:wizard.fields.color.red
        green = LLL:EXT:bw_focuspoint_images/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:wizard.fields.color.green
        blue = LLL:EXT:bw_focuspoint_images/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:wizard.fields.color.blue
    }
}

link {
    title = LLL:EXT:bw_focuspoint_images/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:wizard.fields.link
    type = link
}
```

}

I have inserted a link field for my extra image field. But when I link the image from the file it is not working. Below is the way I am inserting image and result what I get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaykZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1MAI.png)

Here is the code for image.

```
 <img src="{point.image}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this extension. The field type `file` is not supported. Since the whole wizard opens in a quite complex modal, this is not necessary. To reference files, use the type `link`: Upload your files via Filelist and link through the wizard.

Comment: How can i get id of each focus point on the image? Please help

Comment: You mean in the frontend? Use <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug> to see the whole output. In the default template, all infos are stored inside the {points} array - there you can use the f:for viewhelper with iteration to use the index as IDs. Or you add an input in the backend to add a dedicated ID.

Comment: Actually i want to display prev and next focuspoint. can i get that by using iteration?

Comment: I am getting an issue with displaying images. can you please help? I have updated the issue in my question.